# Extending Hangfire Dashboard

Tags: c#, .net, razor, hangfire

I wanted to ask you if anyone tried extending their Hangfire dashboard? There seem to be some tips, by the author of package, but they are the rest of the owl type tips.

I want to extend my dashboard with additional columns, Tenant column and Entity Type.

I installed RazorGenerator as per this thread: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/593
and then I have created a view `RecurringJobsPage.cshtml` with code:

```
@* Generator: Template
   TypeVisibility: Internal
   GeneratePrettyNames: true
   Namespace: Hangfire.Dashboard.Pages
*@

@using Hangfire.Dashboard
@inherits RazorPage


<div>
   TEST
</div>
```

It generated the class for it, but it has a bunch of errors like `CS0115    '_Views_Hangfire_RecurringJobsPage.ExecuteAsync()': no suitable method found to override` etc.
Can anyone share a code that they have used to extend their dashboard??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be very limited documentation for this. I have used this post in the past which breaks the task down nicely

[extend hangfire dashboard](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/dashboard-extension/1371/4)

Comment: Yup I have seen it, but still cannot follow it :/